# Edit script to apply across all sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

This is the script that I am using currently. I want it to apply to all sheets in my document automatically. Please help. The following is the code.

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;
// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1];
// Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = '46'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

I want the script to execute on every sheet so that whenever I add a new sheet the script runs automatically and helps me add a time stamp to column two when I add a value to column 1.

Please help.

I am a complete noob here and as such some detailed explanation will help me immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, just remove the `if` statement and the code will apply to EVERY sheet.

In the answer given below, I've also used some of the objects returned by the onEdit trigger.

---

```
/**
* Creates a Date Stamp if a column is edited.
*/

//CORE VARIABLE
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 1;

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == COLUMNTOCHECK){
    // edited the right column do something
    var targetcell = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2);
    targetcell.setValue(new Date());
  }
  else {
  // do nothing
  }
}
```