# Apply app script project to all sheets in a google drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory

I have created an app script project that is linked to a specific google sheet (in the sheet I clicked on app script project and when I call it I do `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`).

However, I want this script to apply to all of the sheets inside a specific google drive folder. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for quite a long time but I still haven't reached to any conclusion. Some of the pages that I visited include: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67980472/how-to-apply-a-google-script-across-all-sheets-in-a-folder) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992007/edit-script-to-apply-across-all-sheets)

The project is pretty complex and I don't think it is worth explaining it, however, if it is needed I wouldn't mind doing it.

If more information or clarification is needed, just say me and I will add the necessary information. I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a [container-bound script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) tied to a spreadsheet.

What you need is a [standalone script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that locates the folder by its name or its ID using the `Drive` service, finds the files in that folder, identifies spreadsheets among those files, and does its thing with those spreadsheets.

The questions you link to are not relevant here. They iterate *sheets*, i.e., tabs within a spreadsheet file, whereas you are trying to to iterate spreadsheet files.

Comment: Your question did not mention the need to get triggers to fire for multiple spreadsheets. That concept is quite different from "script to apply to all of the sheets inside a specific google drive folder," which implies iteration. Please research [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and post another question if necessary.